# How to deploy on heroku successfully

Tags: node.js, heroku-postgres

I just deployed my web app on heroku; it didn't render, so I added

```js
app.get('/',(req,res) =>{
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../index.html'))
})
```

in server.js. But the index CSS styling and other pages are not rendering.
This is my folder structure: https://github.com/Adegbite1999/MyDiary

PS: I am using plain HTML, CSS, and JavaScript; no frameworks or libraries. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: As far as we can see you're _only_ serving the index HTML file. That won't work anywhere, let alone on Heroku. If you're serving static content, have you looked into [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static)?

Comment: I suggest adding the relevant bits of your index.html and express config to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your repo, you have:

```js
app.use(express.static((__dirname + '../UI/styles')))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../UI/images'))
```

But you reference it like this:

```html
<head>

  <!-- ... -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./UI/styles/index.css">
</head>
<body>

  <!-- ... -->

  <script src="./UI/lib/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is not how `express.static` works. Take a look at the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) (emphasis added):

> For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public:
>
> ```js
> app.use(express.static('public'))
> ```
>
> Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:
>
> ```text
> http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
> http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
> http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
> http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
> http://localhost:3000/hello.html
> ```
>
> **Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the name of the static directory is not part of the URL.**

Currently, express will interpret your request like so:

- `./UI/styles/index.css`:

  - Try `__dirname + '../UI/styles' + '/UI/styles/index.css'`: Not found
  - Try `__dirname + '../UI/images' + '/UI/styles/index.css'`: Not found

### Solution

Either change your links to match the roots specified in your express server (i.e. change `href="./UI/styles/index.css"` to `href="index.css"`), or change your express configuration to use virtual paths (also in the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)):

```js
app.use(express.static('/UI/styles', __dirname + '../UI/styles'));
app.use(express.static('/UI/images', __dirname + '../UI/images'));
```

I'd suggest having one main static directory if possible. You could do it like this:

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../UI'));
// reference it in markup like: href="/styles/index.css"
```